# Getting news from the site

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

Necessary, through certain sections of time, to get a reference to the first news of the list on site http://mediametrics.ru/rating/ru/online.html.

I am developing through the Python, Selenium. 
I tried different ways: and read html, and try to get a response from JavaScript, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

OK, been trying different things to help solve your problem. Finally I got an idea.

So basically you can't rely the static html that you get by accessing that page. So, looking at the `Network` tab in my browser, I found two requests made very X seconds (haven't paid attention to that).
So you can get your first information (top on the list by calling this url):

```
http://mediametrics.ru/rating/ru/online.tsv?page=1&update=1401216280
```

The last parameter `update` you will need to change it accordingly to the moment you make a request. It's a epoch time.
From that request you get a response of content type `text/plain`. Unfortunately, it's not your greatest reponse:

```
URL Title   Visitors    Delta   Shift   ID  819 1401216700  0
        508 -7  0   88680394    
        247 4   0   88193830    
        137 0   -1  88777121    
        135 -3  1   88585317    
        110 -3  -5  12773355    hot
        92  0   0   88724182    
        79  -2  0   88171489    
        76  1   0   88325612    
        59  -3  0   88362537    
        58  -2  0   88585583    
        48  0   -1  88473319    
        47  0   -1  88782428    
        46  0   -31 88470684    hot2
        45  -5  1   88865695    
        44  1   -1  88652852    
        44  2   -1  88679946    
        43  -1  2   88711744    
        40  1   0   88652022    
        38  1   0   88681949    
        37  0   -1  88359733    
        36  2   -2  88612187    
        35  1   -18 88671532    hot
        35  -2  0   88324438    
        34  1   0   88869913    
        34  1   0   88586542    
        33  0   0   88509191    
        33  0   2   88717302    
        32  0   -20 88603116    hot
        31  -2  2   88176393    
        30  0   -30 88644435    hot2
        29  1   0   88686770    
        28  -2  0   88213989    
        26  0   -1  88562683    
        24  -3  2   88634740    
        24  0   -12 88247749    hot
        24  0   0   88257193    
        24  0   0   88350559    
        21  -2  0   88682576    
        21  0   -4  88847895    
        19  0   -1  88864392    
        19  0   -1  88677033    
        19  0   -3  88850105    
        18  0   0   88658580    
        17  0   -3  88649865    
        17  1   -18 88578308    hot
        17  1   5   88326429    
        16  0   -1  88285506    
        16  -1  0   88603395    
        15  -2  4   88527942    
        15  2   -16 88199416
```

Basically, from the second column, you want the 4th field (i.e. `88680394`).
This will only give you your id of the site, to get the rest of the information from this "site id", you need to make another request to this page, specifying your previously extracted "site id":

```
http://mediametrics.ru/rating/index.tsv?titles=88680394
```

This will return the following response:

```
russian.rt.com/article/33873    Ополченцы ДНР: К нам пришло большое подкрепление    0   0   0   88680394    hot
```

From this last response you can complete your needed information. 
I have not given an actual implementation, but having into consideration that you mentioned that you have tried Python, I presume it will be easier from here for your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If I correct understand You....., try to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

[Here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-python) You can find really good tutorial.